# Why did future Flash save his child-self from Reverse Flash only once?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash (2014)*,

> Reverse Flash travelled back in time to kill Flash when he was kid. Flash followed him and saved his child-self once and returned to his own time.

Now, the question is: Why didn't Flash stay with his child-self or with Reverse Flash to save himself? Why did he return knowing Reverse Flash could go after his child-self again? In fact, Reverse Flash did get the chance to kill Barry and nobody was there to protect him. I hardly doubt that the future Flash knew that Reverse Flash would stuck and he would need his past-self to return and he wasn't psychopath enough to drop the idea of returning home over the idea of killing Flash.

Comment: He didn't need to do it a second time since he knew - from his own experience - that the first attempt was successful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the show is concerned we don't know. In fact it appears that the future flash is still missing, so we don't even know if he ended up back in his own time, but it appears he didn't.

[image]

Throughout season 1 Harrison Wells keeps reading this news article over and over again. Presumably this article is in reference to the future he came from/the future they are all headed too. The fact that the day after the Flash's battle in which he followed the Reverse Flash back in time the news say he's missing, leads us to believe that Future flash never made it back, and may still be in our current timeline, OR met another fate.

Comment: My question is: Why did he even try to return?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 and i answered we have no idea if he tried or not, we just know that he currently isnt back.

Comment: Hmmm that is interesting Wayne tech and queen inc merge? :)